# Avoid duplicates in insert

Tags: sql, db2

I have to insert data into table, but this table have unique constraints on two columns **`column_1`** and **`column_2`**. Now during insert process I'm getting following error:

> Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [23505] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0803N  One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1" constrains table "table_name" from having duplicate values for the index key.  SQLSTATE=23505.

How can avoid this error?

Comment: see https://www.withdata.com/blog/db2/replace-update-or-insert-a-row-into-db2-table-merge-into.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manged to solvit by using NOT EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an "upsert = update or insert" semantics. In DB2, this can be achieved in the following manner (example taken from [here](https://www.withdata.com/blog/db2/replace-update-or-insert-a-row-into-db2-table-merge-into.html)):

```
MERGE INTO employees AS tab
USING (VALUES
        (123456,'smith','bob')
    ) AS merge (id,last_name,first_name)
    ON tab.id = merge.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET tab.id = merge.id,
                   tab.last_name = merge.last_name,
                   tab.first_name = merge.first_name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (id,last_name,first_name)
        VALUES (merge.id, merge.last_name, merge.first_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

While doing insert just check whether those column values are already exist in the table or not, if not then insert otherwise it wont give any result.

```
Insert into yourtable(required columns or u can omit if all)
Select ur columns from othertable where (column1,column2) not in 
(Select column1,column2 from yourtable)
```

Comment: I've done this using not exists command, but thanks it also was helpful.